# How do I remove any string from array of strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove strings from a url in jQuery but the url may or may not have a trailing slash or something after it.

I need to replicate this PHP function but in jQuery or javascript.

```
$poss = array("/About", "/about", "/Gig", "/gig", "/tracks", "/Tracks"); 
$url = str_replace($poss, "", $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the PHP you posted correctly, then you need something like this:

```
var poss = ["/About", "/about", "/Gig", "/gig", "/tracks", "/Tracks"];
for(var i = 0; i<poss.length; i++) {
    url = url.replace(poss[i], "");
}
```

It's really best to attempt to figure this sort of thing out on your own, however, since you won't really benefit from being given the answer as much as you would from implementing it yourself. Furthermore, this is a site to come from if you have question about stuff you've already tried to write, and you don't seem to have made any attempts to solve your problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
var array = new Array("/About", "/about", "/Gig", "/gig", "/tracks", "/Tracks"),
    url = "test/About/about/Gig";
array.filter(function (el, i, arr) {
    url = url.replace(el, el.replace('/', ''));
});
alert(url); // testAboutaboutGig
```

Comment: `Array.map` isn't supported in older browsers, IIRC.

Comment: It is supported in older browsers, but only in IE9 for the IE "family" IIRC

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was remembering. Also, I don't think you interpreted his question correctly. Where does the URL factor into your answer?

Comment: Can be easily prototyped for the older browsers, so it's all good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap

Comment: I didn't know how `str_replace` worked with arrays, I thought it returned a new array. My bad, edited the answer.